# Count combinations between columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a dataframe like this

```
   V1 V2 V3
1  A  A  A
2  B  A  A
3  A  B  C
4  C  A  A
```

With this code i get another dataframe with all the possible combinations with "A", "B", "C".

```
library("gtools")
vars <- c("A", "B", "C")
combMatrix <- (combinations(n = 3, r = 2, repeats.allowed = T, v = vars))
combArray <- paste(combMatrix [,1], combMatrix [,2], sep="")
combDf <- expand.grid(combArray ,vars)
```

Then I want to count the combinations between a couple of two columns in the first dataframe(let's say V1 and V2) and the other column, and it's important to consider the concatenated characters (V1+V2 in this case) like "AB" and "BA" as the same combination.
The final data frame should look like this.

```
V1+V2 V3 Freq
AA    A  1
AB    A  1
AC    A  1
BB    A  0
BC    A  0
CC    A  0
AA    B  0
AB    B  0
AC    B  0
BB    B  0
BC    B  0
CC    B  0
AA    C  0
AB    C  1   
AC    C  0
BB    C  0
BC    C  0
CC    C  0
```

Then I have to iterate the process for every combinations of columns (V1+V2/V3, V1+V3/V2, V2+V3/V1).

Comment: @Jimbou because the combination BB(V1+V2) B(V3) is not present in the dataframe

Comment: please see my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `tidyverse` solution.
First calculate all possible 18 combinations considering AB==BA for two variables using some magic and not-so-elegant code including `map`, `unite`, `sort` and `paste` together with `rowwise`.

```
library(tidyverse)
all_combs <- expand.grid(unique(unlist(d)),unique(unlist(d)),unique(unlist(d))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  mutate(two=paste(sort(c(Var1,Var2)), collapse="")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unite(all, two, Var3) %>% 
  select(all) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Then the rest

```
combn(1:ncol(d),2, simplify = F) %>% 
  set_names(map(.,~paste(., collapse = "&"))) %>% 
  map(~select(d,a =.[1], b=.[2], everything()) %>% 
        rowwise() %>% 
        mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
        mutate(two=paste(sort(c(a, b)), collapse="")) %>% 
        select(two, contains("V"), -a,-b) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        unite(all, two, contains("V")) %>% 
        count(all)) %>% 
  map(~right_join(.,all_combs, by="all")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>% 
  mutate(n=ifelse(is.na(n), 0, n)) %>% 
  spread(id, n)
# A tibble: 18 x 4
   all    `1&2`  `1&3`  `2&3`
   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 AA_A       1      1      1
 2 AA_B       0      0      1
 3 AA_C       0      0      1
 4 AB_A       1      1      0
 5 AB_B       0      0      0
 6 AB_C       1      0      0
 7 AC_A       1      1      0
 8 AC_B       0      1      0
 9 AC_C       0      0      0
10 BB_A       0      0      0
11 BB_B       0      0      0
12 BB_C       0      0      0
13 BC_A       0      0      1
14 BC_B       0      0      0
15 BC_C       0      0      0
16 CC_A       0      0      0
17 CC_B       0      0      0
18 CC_C       0      0      0
```